# Get the value of the clicked element on angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I started working with angular about 2 days ago. I'm still wrapping my head around how to do many things. Right now, I am trying to have a tooltip appear with the information pertaining the clicked "tag". I defined a "tag" as a `<span>` element with a `ng-toolkit`like so:

```
<div id="list-of-words" ng-controller="inlineEditorController" ng-click="hideTooltip()">
    <!-- This is the tooltip. It is shown only when the showtooltip variable is truthful -->
    <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-show="showtooltip">
        <input type="text" ng-model="value" />
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="w in words">
      <span class="tag" ng-click="toggleTooltip($event)">{{w.content}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my controller is as such:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('inlineEditorController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.inlineEditor = function(){
        $scope.showtooltip = false;
        $scope.value = 'Edit me.';

        $scope.hideTooltip = function(){
            $scope.showtooltip = false;
        }

        $scope.toggleTooltip = function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $scope.showtooltip = !$scope.showtooltip;
        }
    };
})]);
```

what I'm attempting to do is to change the 'Edit me.' to display the content from `{{w.content}}` but I have no idea how to do this. Everything I've tried so far has failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get item content you can use:

```
      <span class="tag" ng-click="toggleTooltip($event,w.content)">{{w.content}}</span>
```

So, controller should be:

```
 $scope.toggleTooltip = function(e,content){
            e.stopPropagation();
            $scope.showtooltip = !$scope.showtooltip;
            $scope.value = content;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$event.currentTarget` to get the element. i.e. `e.currentTarget` in your controller.